# Magento Soap API v2 shoppingCartOrder() not working in case of discount amount

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I have used Magento Soap API v2 to create Mobile APP API. For order place I have created a function in which I used API shoppingCartOrder(), this API works perfect when no discount amount added to cart items.

But when I added discount amount on cart Items then discount amount not added to cart totals.

My Custom function code for place order is below :

```
...
// cart info after apply discount amount
$cartTotal = $soapClient->shoppingCartTotals($sessionId, $cartId);
{ $cartTotal not showing discount amount }

// place the order
$orderId = $soapClient->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $cartId, '1', '1');
...
```

How to add discount amount in cart total in soap API?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing store ID in the **shoppingCartCouponAdd** API call.
 Here is the complete script to place order using **Magento SOAP API V2** with **Discount Code** :

```
$storeId = '1';

$quoteId = $client->shoppingCartCreate($session,$storeId);

echo "<br>Quote ID : " . $quoteId;

/* Set cart customer */
$guest = true;

if ($guest) 
{
    $customerData = array(
        "firstname" => "testFirstname",
        "lastname" => "testLastName",
        "email" => "testEmail@mail.com",
        "mode" => "guest",
        "website_id" => "1"
    );
} 
else 
{
    $customer  = array(
        "customer_id" => '69301',
        "website_id" => "1",
        "group_id" => "1",
        "store_id" => "1",
        "mode" => "customer",
    );
}

//Set cart customer (assign customer to quote)
$resultCustomerSet = $client->shoppingCartCustomerSet($session, $quoteId, $customerData,$storeId);

echo "<br>Set Customer: ";
var_dump($resultCustomerSet);   //Set customer

/* Set customer addresses Shipping and Billing */

$addresses = array(
    array(
        "mode" => "shipping",
        "firstname" => "Ahsan",
        "lastname" => "testLastname",
        "company" => "testCompany",
        "street" => "testStreet",
        "city" => "Karachi",
        "region" => "Sindh",
        "postcode" => "7502",
        "country_id" => "PK",
        "telephone" => "0123456789",
        "fax" => "0123456789",
        "is_default_shipping" => 0,
        "is_default_billing" => 0
    ),
    array(
        "mode" => "billing",
        "firstname" => "Ahsan",
        "lastname" => "testLastname",
        "company" => "testCompany",
        "street" => "testStreet",
        "city" => "Karachi",
        "region" => "Sindh",
        "postcode" => "7502",
        "country_id" => "PK",
        "telephone" => "0123456789",
        "fax" => "0123456789",
        "is_default_shipping" => 0,
        "is_default_billing" => 0
    )
);

//Set cart customer address
$resultCustomerAddress = $client->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($session, $quoteId, $addresses,$storeId);   

echo "<br>Set Customer Address: ";
var_dump($resultCustomerAddress);   //Set customer addresses

/* Add products to cart */
$product = array(
                            'product_id' => '905',
                            // 'sku' => 'simple_product',
                            'qty' => '1',
                            'options' => null,
                            'bundle_option' => null,
                            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
                            'links' => null);
$product2 = array(
                            'product_id' => '904',
                            // 'sku' => 'simple_product',
                            'qty' => '2',
                            'options' => null,
                            'bundle_option' => null,
                            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
                            'links' => null);

$addToCart = $client->shoppingCartProductAdd($session, $quoteId, array($product,$product2),$storeId);

echo "<br>Add to Cart: ";
var_dump($addToCart);

/* Set payment method */
$responsePayment = $client->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($session, $quoteId, array(
    'method' => 'cashondelivery',
),$storeId);  

echo "<br>Set Payment method: ";
var_dump($responsePayment);

/* Set shipping method */
$setShipping = $client->shoppingCartShippingMethod($session, $quoteId, 'flatrate_flatrate',$storeId);

echo "<br>Set Shipping method: ";
var_dump($setShipping);

/* Set Discount Code */

try
{
    $result = $client->shoppingCartCouponAdd($session, $quoteId, 'test123',$storeId);
    echo "<br>Apply discount code: ";
    var_dump($result);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo "<br>Discount code Failed: " . $ex->getMessage();
    die();
}


$orderId = $client->shoppingCartOrder($session, $quoteId, $storeId, null);
echo "<br>Placed Order: ";
var_dump($orderId);
```